# border-image fill is strange

Tags: html, css

When I use border-image with the fill, it isn't filled in as a complete image, but separately, and because of the texture on my fill, it looks bad. What can I do?

```
    <td class="heading">
        This is a heading
    </td>

<style>
.heading {
padding:10px;
border-style: solid; 
border-width: 27px 51px 27px 27px; 
-moz-border-image: url('http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/4189/brownfill.png') 27 51 27 27 repeat; 
-webkit-border-image: url('http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/4189/brownfill.png') 27 51 27 27 repeat;
 -o-border-image: url('http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/4189/brownfill.png') 27 51 27 27 repeat; 
border-image: url('http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/4189/brownfill.png') 27 51 27 27 fill repeat;
}
</style>
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zWygk/

[image]

Comment: First off, I don't quite get why you're using tables.
Try using div's instead.

Also; you're using a border image that's 400 x 400 px. Wich isn't going to fit.
Could you explain what it is you're trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: Secondly, that image isn't good for repeating vertically it appears. If the container you're filling is bigger than that image, it's going to look wonky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must agree with Jefferson that your image is not an ideal choice. The exact answer to your question therfore is "get a different image!" 
For further reading, I advice consulting Chris's article: http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

In short: the image needs to consist of 9 slices total. 4 for the corners, 4 for the actual borders/sides and 1 for the body of the container (can be blank)

You should also know that your slices will be stretched if your border-width exceeds the height (top/bottom border) or width (left/right border) of your slices. Only the other dimension can be set with the argument repeat/stretch